# How to determine whether a value exists in a junction table and return zero or one?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

I am trying to write a single query that will return only exactly what I need. I will drop in a MovieID and get back a list of ALL genres. If the movie represents a specific genre (has an associated record in the junction table), the Checked value will be 1. If not, then 0.

My result set should look like this:

```
GenreID    Genre    Checked
1          ABC      0
2          DEF      1
3          HIJ      0
4          KLM      1
```

My First table is named Genres. It looks like this:

```
GenreID    Genre
1          ABC
2          DEF
3          HIJ
4          KLM
```

My second table is named Movies.  It looks like this:

```
MovieID   Title
1         Blah
2         Foo
3         Carpe
4         Diem
```

My third table is a junction table named Movies_Genres. It looks like this:

```
MovieID   GenreID
1         2
1         1
1         4
2         1
2         3
3         4
4         1
```

I would normally, do a couple of queries and a couple of loops to handle this, but I want to really just make the database do the work here.  How do I tweak my query so that I can get the resultset that I need with just a single query?

Here's the starting query:

```
SELECT  GenreID, 
        Genre
FROM    Genres
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Which MovieID produces the result where only Genres 2 and 4 are checked? The desired result doesn't seem to match your sample data.

Comment: It's not real data. It's fake, sample data so that you could see the table layout. You couldn't product the exact results with any query. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: But even fake data should make some sense. Checked should be 1 for MovieID 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT g.GenreID, g.Genre, Checked = CASE WHEN EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Movies_Genres AS mg
         INNER JOIN dbo.Movies AS m
         ON mg.MovieID = m.MovieID
         WHERE mg.GenreID = g.GenreID
         AND m.MovieID = @MovieID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.Genres AS g
ORDER BY g.GenreID;
```

If there is a unique constraint or primary key on `dbo.Movies_Genres(MovieID, GenreID)` then this can be simply:

```
SELECT g.GenreID, g.Genre, Checked = COUNT(mg.GenreID)
    FROM dbo.Genres AS g
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Movies_Genres AS mg
    ON g.GenreID = mg.GenreID
    AND mg.MovieID = @MovieID
    GROUP BY g.GenreID, g.Genre;
```

...since the count for any genre can only be 0 or 1 given a single `@MovieID`.

Comment: You need to move the WHERE condition inside the nested SELECT, m.MovieID is undefined outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, I did that when I edited, didn't mean to leave two where clauses in there. My original query assumed the whole set was desired.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight forward using CASE;

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.GenreID, g.Genre, 
  CASE WHEN mg.MovieID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Checked
FROM Genres g 
LEFT JOIN Movies_Genres mg
  ON g.GenreID=mg.GenreID 
    AND mg.MovieId=@MovieID;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0b15/5).

Edit: If entries are guaranteed to be unique in Movies_Genres, you could choose to drop the DISTINCT.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's where the original question wants to drop in a movie ID to analyze all genres for. In this case cut'n'pasted from the demo as a declared variable, but if the SQL is generated one can just put the id of the movie right in.

Answer (score 1):

The `@MovieID` is the movie, you want to filter by.

```
SELECT  Genres.GenreID, 
        Genres.Genre,
        CASE WHEN (Movies_Genres.GenreID IS NULL)
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1 
        END AS Checked
FROM    Genres LEFT JOIN
        Movies_Genres ON Movies_Genres.GenreID = Genres.GenreID AND
                        MovieID = @MovieID
```

Comment: This will produce the same row twice if two movies in a genre have been checked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yep, forgot the `DISTINCT`... The `@MovieID` is consumed to be a procedure's parameter for filtering

Comment: Sorry, missed the "single movie" requirement because of the desired results.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yep, there couldn't be two movies